# Error when trying to publish node project to Nexus[Jenkins-Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

with Jenkins I get an error when trying to publish node project(React app) to Nexus.

**Pipeline Script:**

```
node ("test-label") {
    stage('checkout'){
            sh 'git clone -b react-1 https://gitlab.com/.../ui/test.git .'
    }
    stage ('Build'){
        container('node'){
            script {
                sh "set +x && echo \"//mynexusurl/repository/npm-private/:_authToken=NpmToken.******\" >> .npmrc"
                sh 'npm publish'
          }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in to https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

If I add the following code to the package.json file in the project, it works fine, but I don't want to enter this information in the package.json file.

```
"publishConfig": {
    "registry": "http://mynexus/repository/npm-private/"
}
```

How can I fix **package.json** *without* giving **publishConfig** information?

Comment: You should scope your package and associate that scope with your nexus repository. For an entrypoint to the subject, see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem as follows

```
sh "npm publish --registry http://nexusurl/repository/npm-private/"
```